# in build variable to detect rerun of failed builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there an inbuilt pipeline or build variable to check if the run is actually a re-run of a job/stage.

I need to add this in condition as some of the steps needs to be skipped based on this variable.

```
- conditions: rerun()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are variables regarding this:

`System.JobAttempt` - Set to 1 the first time this job is attempted, and increments every time the job is retried.

`System.StageAttempt` - Set to 1 the first time this stage is attempted, and increments every time the job is retried.

You can find the full variable list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [predefinded variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables) `System.JobAttempt` or `System.StageAttempt` to determine if it is a re-run of a job/stage.

To skip a step if it is a re-run of a job/stage, you can set the condtion as below:

`condition: eq(variables['System.JobAttempt'], '1')`